# Run npm package installed on parent folder

Tags: npm, webpack, npm-install, npm-run

I have folder structure of my project

```
project-root
|- sub-module1
|- sub-module2
```

and on project-root I have `package.json` with `webpack` in it so it gets installed on root of the project.
Inside sub-module folders I have `package.json` where I have specified a script command:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:prod": "webpack -p --config config/webpack.prod.js"
}
```

but running `npm run build:all` gives me an error saying

> [ERROR] sh: webpack: command not found

Is there something I need to specify in submodule package.json, or is this implementation even possible?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to install webpack webpack-cli modules from npm

```
    $ npm install -g webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

then `webpack` command on shell will be work.

Comment: I do not want to install stuff globally on the system, just inside my project and all childs to share same repo